# Weighted average of samples of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables which are possibly correlated. Let $X_1$,$X_2$,…,$X_n$ be random samples of $X$ (which are iid), and $Y_1$,$Y_2$,…,$Y_n$ be the corresponding samples of $Y$. Let $Z$ be defined as
$$Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}$$
which can be seen to be an $X_i$ weighted average of $Y_i$.

In general, the expectation of a ratio is not the ratio of the expectations. But here, under what conditions is 
$$E[Z] = \frac{E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i]}{E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]}?$$

**Update**
My original thought was that if we are able to show$$E[Z] = \frac{E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i]}{E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]},$$ always holds, then
$$\frac{E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i]}{E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_iY_i]}{\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]}=\frac{nE[X_iY_i]}{nE[X_i]}=\frac{E[X_iY_i]}{E[X_i]}=\frac{E[XY]}{E[X]},$$

which are quantities that have extensively studied. Then, $E[Z] = E[Y]$ iff $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

The motivation for this originally came from a musing about a personal finance/business problem. For example, $X_i$ could represent the quantity of apples we buy on store visit $i$, and $Y_i$ could be the average price of an apple for trip $i$. And $Z$ would be the average price not for a given trip, but in $n$ trips. The above question I posed would then help answer: when is $E[Z] = E[Y]$?

Note that sometimes $X$ and $Y$ may be correlated: the more apples you buy, the cheaper it may be for that trip (negative correlation). Or they may be positive correlated (often seen in online freemium games) - you may get the first "fuel" for free, but then you have to pay increasing cost to procure additional "fuel".

Comment: In general we cannot say much about "when" the expectation of the ratio happens to be the ratio of the expectations beyond what you've already said.  One important case is when the distribution of random variables $X_i$ is essentially that of a constant, but of course when that happens we are unlikely to have been thinking of those terms as "random" samples.

Comment: Some good context to add would be: why do you want to know this? Is it an exercise from a book, or a problem you encountered while trying to do something else (what?), or just curiosity?

Comment: (Responding because of your Meta post). Your question is clearly written and sufficiently detailed, but I suspect the answer to "under what conditions" is going to be something like "practically never" or "only when the $X_i$ are essentially constants (as @hardmath mentions)". So people would probably like more details about the motivation for the question, or why you may suspect there would a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - I just got back a trip. I thought about this a bit more, and it seems the independence of X and Y may be one condition, in addition to the condition of being "constants". I posted this in an answer below to avoid cluttering up the question space. I am now wondering if these are necessary conditions... And Matthew Towers, thanks for the tip. I've added additional context and original motivation for my question.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this more, I was able to show the above holds if $X$ and $Y$ are independent (derivation below). But I have yet to determine if this independence is a necessary condition.

(Please excuse the image - I was on a flight and did not have access to a MathJax tool.)
[image]